# Handling AJAX callback

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm writing a script that will send user details to a PHP script via AJAX. Currently the PHP script works fine. No problems there. I'd like to know how the callback should be handled.

Should I point it to the existing PHP script, or should I create a new file specifically for processing AJAX requests (creating redundant code)?

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'existing-script.php',
// OR url: 'callback.php',
success: function(feedback){

    alert(feedback);

}
```

EDIT:

The PHP currently inserts the users personal details (name, etc.) as well as uploads images. It's a wizard that builds an account once the user signs up. This action is shared between the AJAX (Wizard) and the standard "Edit your profile" page

Comment: both options are equally valid based on the information supplied

Comment: The answer is: it depends, on a lot of things. What does the PHP currently do? Is it run often? If it has any functionality that the AJAX processor will need then you might write the code there or include it in a new file with a require statement. We need more info.

Comment: Thanks everyone. What I'd like to know is what is the best practice. The PHP currently inserts the users personal details (name, etc.) as well as uploads images. It's a wizard that builds an account once the user signs up.

Comment: you have not provided enough information say what"best practice" is, it all depends in the circumstances.

Comment: @Dagon - Fair enough. It's just hard to dump all the info here. Just wondering if there was an accepted best practice similar to not writing inline CSS etc. Thanks

Comment: there is no "best practice" in any field with out taking the  circumstances in to consideration. I write inline css every day (when used for html formatted email) -- get the point

Comment: I would always return JSON and handle that from your JavaScript.

Comment: @Paul: please update the question with the script's tasks and other requested information. In general, respond to requests for clarifications by updating your post rather than replying with a comment. For one thing, a question should be understandable without reading comments. For another, SO is a Q&A site, not a forum, and comments aren't intended (nor are they well suited) for discussions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [REST](http://tomayko.com/writings/rest-to-my-wife) principles, URIs are [names for resources](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1). Client side, you should use the same URI only when accessing the same resource. Ask yourself what resources the site makes available.

Server side, you can map a URI to any script when handling a request. Often, the mapping is 1-1 (a separate script for each URI) or all-1 (where a single script serves as the entry point to handle all requests) for simplicity's sake, but you could use some other mapping, depending on what makes sense for your project. If having one script handle user profile updating and image upload is a good design, go with it. As for what counts as "good design", it's a matter of picking an architectural pattern that promotes your project's development goals (e.g. short development time, allows team to work effectively, easy maintenance) and sticking to that pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I ususally find it easy to have a seperate URI for AJAX requests and a seperate URI for normal web requests

The reason being ... response returned by AJAX is much more compact than the one that render a HTML page (it includes a bunch of styling and html tags ... that I do not use for handling AJAX requests)

Also, if you seperate the business logic and presentation ... you really do not need to duplicate the code. The code to calculate the user preferences can be shared between the two actions

The two actions just use this code to get the user preferences ... and depending on whether it is for AJAX or for HTML ... it can package the response appropriately